# How to evaluate percentage of ETR TO APPLY THE CONDITION?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to calculate etr_time (%) in group by name. If Respose_Time>Etr_Time then 
100 % and Etr_Time

```
NAME      PROBLEM      Response_Time                ETR_Time
Sudip     Hardware     0:30:00 (hours)               1:00:00 (hours)
sudip     software     0:30:00 (hours)               0:15:00 (hours)
Amol      Hardware     0:30:00 (hours)               1:00:00 (hours)
```

I want to result

```
NAME           ETR_Time_%
Sudip          50%
Amol           100%
```

Comment: Calculate % of what?

Comment: if response_time>etr_time then 100%

Comment: For Amol Response_Time is 30 minutes, ETR_Time is 60 minutes, and you want 100% returned. And Sudip has two rows in the table, but you only want one row back - what to do?

Comment: Sudip one problems done in right time, next time is done wrong time so avg_percent is 50%. Amol done in right time so percentage is 100%

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `case` expression to do conditional counting of problems solved within time. Divide that count by the person's total count.

```
select name,
       100 * count(case when Response_Time < ETR_Time then 1 end) / count(*) as "ETR_Time_%"
from tablename
group by name
```

Comment: @denny, does MySQL want back-ticks, or will standard double quotes work as well?

Comment: you know better then me but your query got syntax error to me.

Comment: i use back-ticks for reserved keyword...and double quotes for alias

Comment: @denny, now delimited with double quotes. ANSI SQL compliant!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select Name, 
       TotalTime, 
       TotalETR, 
       case when TotalTime > TotalETR then 100
            when TotalETR = 0 then 0
            else TotalTime/TotalETR * 100
       end as ETR_PC
from
(
select Name, 
       sum(Response_Time) as TotalTime,
       sum(ETR_TIME) as TotalETR
from MyTable
group by Name
) x1
```